# How do I run a Spacy Model on publicly accessible server?

Tags: python, flask, nlp, localhost, spacy

I'm running a language analysis program with python. I already have the following code running on my localhost:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import en_core_web_sm
from rules import *

nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/api/rule1', methods=['POST'])
def process_text_r1():
    try:
        text = request.json.get('text', '')

        if not text:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Text not provided'}), 400

        result = rule1(nlp,text)
        return jsonify({'result': result})

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Internal server error', 'message': str(e)}), 500
```

I want to be able to run it from a publicly accessible server.

I tried uploading the app to vercel, but then Vercel warned that it exceeded the limits for an app. The limit is 50MB, so I don't get how it got so big given that my code is just 8KB.

I've tried creating an app on a hosting provider (namecheap), but the process seems too convoluted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app probably exceeded the 50mb limit because the `en_core_web_sm` model is about 12mb itself and with the other libraries (e.g., request, jsonify) your app is actually more than 50mb, although your source code is 8kb.

Hosting providers like namecheap are not the best option because their platforms are mostly designed for serving webpages, so they only support a few common deployment processes (e.g., Wordpress, PHP, node.js).

You can try a few alternative options:

- https://www.pythonanywhere.com/ gives 512mb to free accounts.
- You can try to use the Google Cloud engine, which has a generous free tier: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime
- Heroku's cheapest plan would cost around $5-$9 but if you are a student, you may qualify for the free credit through GitHub's education pack (https://www.heroku.com/github-students)

Comment: pythonanywhere.com works even if I spent a good part of today trying to configure it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I never tried running a spacy model on it. Was there anything specific or any tricks you needed to get it to work? @DavidWarutumo

Comment: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask/ gives a good description of how to go about this. Uploading files is done one by one. But the 512MB really helped. You create a console and pip install spacy on a virtual environment. Then you link that virtual environment folder with you flask app in the app details